# Is it possible to convert OneNote 2010 notebooks to a web notebook?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010, windows-live-sync

Like most people I've got a bunch of local OneNote 2010 notebooks (2010 format).  I want to use the new feature to sync with Windows Live but I don't see an option to convert them.  If this isn't possible then an option would be to copy the content from the local-only notebook to the web notebook buy I don't see a way to copy all sections and pages at once - it would be laborious if I had to do the sections individually.

Also related to web notebooks, is it possible to sync multiple PCs with a single web-based notebook?  So that if I use multiple PCs with OneNote installed I can get the richer experience.

Comment: Comment from @Ape-inago: Is it possible that you are trying to share a Notebook created with ON 2007? I've had problems doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your Notebook online with **File -> Share**.

Yes, it is possible to use a notebook with multiple PCs, companies do this for collaborative productivity...

Comment: Furthermore, if other people edit stuff your attention is drawn to it by the section and page going bold so you can home in and see what has been added, removed etc (fairly sure there is also some kind of rollback, but not certain on this).
Great video on OneNote 2010 - stuff about sharing starts at 1:30 or so, but the whole thing is worth watching. http://vimeo.com/12216684

Comment: Yes, under View you can show or hide the authors so you can see in detail what has last been touched by who, you can also right click on a note and show previous versions (as AdamV mentions) and restore them.

Comment: TomWij and guys - Love it!  Simple answer and I just did it!

Comment: TomWiJ - If I create a new web notebook from the start and then I create sections, etc., they all sync to the web fine.  However, if I do a file/share on an existing notebook, I see the notebook on office live and the section groups are there, but they are empty and the sections doesn't exist either.  Thoughts?  Also how can you unsync a notebook?

Comment: I'm not using this myself, let me check how it works...

Comment: Works fine here... Right click on the notebook and check the sync status and try syncing again. You can try deleting the notebook online and see if it still occurs in OneNote, another way would be to create a new notebook with a temporary name and dragging all the sections to that one. Then remove the old one and rename the new one.

Comment: @tomWij - a little more info.  When my notebook syncs I get error "An error occurred while attempting to sync this section or notebook.  Error code 0xE4010646.".  That error code literally produced no results on Google.  So frustrating!

Comment: That seems annoying, I can't find something either...

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to share a Notebook created with ON 2007?  I've had problems doing that.